# How to get facebook friends from facebook graph api in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I am not able to get the friends list from the facebook graph api.

it is throwing exception the Bad request.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="accessTokenString";
here is my code

```
 public IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessCode, string redirectURI)
    {

        string token = GetHTML(Facebook_GraphAPI_Token + "client_id=" + AppID + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(redirectURI) + "%3F__provider__%3Dfacebook" + "&client_secret=" + AppSecret + "&code=" + accessCode);
        if (token == null || token == "")
        {
            return null;
        }


        string friendsData = Web.GetHTML(Facebook_GraphAPI_Friends + "fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email,username,gender,link,bio,birthday,friendlists,friends&access_token=" + token.Substring("access_token=", "&"));
        //string substringToken=token.Substring("access_token=", "&");
        //string friendsData = Web.GetHTML(Facebook_GraphAPI_Friends + substringToken);


        return friendsData ;
    }





public static string GetHTML(string URL)
    {
        string connectionString = URL;

        try
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);
            myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //// Get the response
            WebResponse webResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            ////
            StreamReader ioStream = new StreamReader(respStream);
            string pageContent = ioStream.ReadToEnd();
            //// Close streams
            ioStream.Close();
            respStream.Close();
            return pageContent;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Show your code that reproduces this problem

Comment: @Sayse plz have a look into my code block i have updated it..Please help me

Comment: I'm not sure but I would imagine its the concatenation done for `friendsData`

Comment: @Sayse it's returning null in friendsData and in exception it is showing Bad request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found wrong fields in friends request api
**friendlists,friends** please remove these fields

Correct End Point
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email,username,gender,link,bio,birthday&access_token={your facebook access token}